# Can I pre-register an SSL certificate with validity in the near future?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

Can I register an SSL certificate that will only start to be valid in the near future and not right away?

Comment: What specific problem would this solve? It sounds a little bit like an X-Y problem...

Comment: What do you mean by "register an SSL certificate"? Do you mean doing the validation now, as well as the issuance of the certificate but have the certificate with a notBefore date in the future? OR doing validation now, but issuing the certificate later? In this second case CABForum documents give time limits on validation reuse, like 13 months in case of EV certificates, or 825 days (section 4.2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, the validity of period of the certificate is not determined by the requestor, and is not specified in the CSR.  The validity period is determined by the CA (most CA's offer various durations according to price).  So, you would have to find a CA that has a mechanism in place for what you are trying to do.

See [CSR expiry date / validity date](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/167629/csr-expiry-date-validity-date) for more info.